Webscraping JavaScript Table with Selenium and Beautiful Soup
I'm trying to scrape this website: https://www.globusmedical.com/patient-education-musculoskeletal-system-conditions/resources/find-a-surgeon/
It appears that the website uses JavaScript so that when I load inspect the code, I don't see the table with the doctors listed. However, when you inspect the element specifically, it's there with all of the information.
I'm trying to click the "Load More" button multiple times until it disappears and then parse through the page with BeautifulSoup.
Could someone help me with why the page_source that's being printed doesn't display any of the information? Is there a while loop you would setup to accomplish clicking "Load More" until it's gone?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
import requests

doctor_dict = {}

#configure webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

driver.get("https://www.globusmedical.com/patient-education-musculoskeletal-system-conditions/resources/find-a-surgeon/")
time.sleep(5)
clickable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@class="js-eml-load-more-button eml-load-more-button eml-btn btn btn--primary"]')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickable)
# items = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"eml-location grid--item")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
driver.quit()


There is an API call to do the same.
API: https://www.globusmedical.com/wp-json/em-locator/v1/locations/?page=1
import requests
from lxml import etree
import json

def get_response_using_headers(page):
    headers = {
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            }

    params = {
            'page': page,
            }

    response = requests.get('https://www.globusmedical.com/wp-json/em-locator/v1/locations/', params=params, headers=headers)
    return response

# api_url = "https://www.globusmedical.com/wp-json/em-locator/v1/locations/?page=1"
doctors_data = []

# you can change the pagination range here
for page in range(1,2):
    response = get_response_using_headers(page)
    data = response.json()
    for item in data:
        info = {}
        info["name"] = item["post"]["post_title"]
        info["location"] = item["name"]
        address = item["formatted_address"]
        if address == "":
            address = item["address"]
        info["address"] = address
        info["phone"] = item["phone"]
        info["email"] = item["email"]
        html_str = item["list_item_html"]
        dom = etree.HTML(html_str)
        info["specialty"] = dom.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'procedures')]/text()")[0].strip()

        doctors_data.append(info)

print(doctors_data)

OUTPUT:
[{'name': 'Aaron Dumont', 'location': 'Tulane University Medical Center', 'address': '1415 Tulane Avenue, Fifth Floor, Neuroscience Center, New Orleans, LA, 70112', 'phone': '(504) 988-5565', 'email': 'adumont2@tulane.edu', 'specialty': 'Adult Deformity, Degenerative Spine, Minimally Invasive Surgery, Robotic Spine Surgery'},
{'name': 'Aaron Greenberg', 'location': 'Hackensack UMC Pascack Valley', 'address': '784 Franklin Avenue', 'phone': '(844) 777-0910', 'email': 'Ajberg214@gmail.com', 'specialty': 'Adult Deformity, Degenerative Spine, Minimally Invasive Surgery'},
.
.
.
{'name': 'Albert Wong', 'location': 'Cedars Sinai and DOCS Health', 'address': '8436 W 3rd St suite 800, Los Angeles, CA, USA', 'phone': '(310) 746-5918', 'email': 'AW@docshealth.com', 'specialty': 'Adult Deformity, Cervical Artificial Disc, Degenerative Spine, Minimally Invasive Surgery, Robotic Spine Surgery, Sacroiliac Joint Fusion, Spinal Deformity, Surgery of the Neck & Back'}]


Thanks for the help! Just curious, where did you find the API/JSON link?

@user3628240 Open the URL and click on inspect (shortcut: ctrl + shift + i ) and then Network section. Now click LOAD MORE button, you can see an api requests going in background and that contains the required data.

You can easily obtain a list of doctors as a JSON object by accessing this URL, without needing to use Selenium and Beautiful Soup. To find the URL, you can simply navigate to Inspect > Network > XHR in your browser. You can rewrite your code as follows:
import requests

url = "https://www.globusmedical.com/wp-json/em-locator/v1/locations/?page=1"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response_dict = response.json()

